# AlertDialog Android "comentario" PopupMenu

Tags: java, android, android-layout, alertdialog

Como faço para obter este resultado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

os 3 pontos nessa imagem já foi pressionado.

Meu layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="3dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageComent"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_perfil"
        android:layout_width="53dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/messageComent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="comentario"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/nameComent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageComent"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageComent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameComent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageComent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageComent"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/messageComent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_3pontos"
            android:cropToPadding="false" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Erro relacionado com a pergunta que tive posteriormente 
[Problema com PopupMenu Recycleradpter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/184083/problema-com-popupmenu-recycleradpter/184087#184087)

Comment: Será que é o que entendi. Você quer mostrar o popup com uma lista de opções certo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É possível criar um *popup* com uma lista de opções usando a classe pública [`PopupMenu`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) adicionado ao Android a partir do [level 11](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels). O `PopupMenu` aparecerá abaixo do item clicado se houver espaço na tela, ou acima se não houver.  Veja abaixo um exemplo básico:

#### Classe

```
btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Criando uma instancia do popup
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, btn);

        //Inflando o popup usando o arquivo xml
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_popup, popup.getMenu());

        //Resgata o item clicado e mostra em um Toast
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                Toast.makeText(GetTextFileByURL.this, "Você clicou em : " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
        popup.show();
    }
});
```

#### Menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:title="Legal"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:title="Bom"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:title="Ótimo"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/four"
        android:title="Espetacular"/>
</menu>
```

#### Imagem

<sup>Em muitos casos, um GIF vale mais que 1000 imagens</sup>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: exatamente oque eu quero, amanhã boto em pratica, obrigado!

Comment: estou tendo problema com o context, porque estou usando RecyclerView ,RecyclerAdapter.

Comment: @WallaceRoberto isso funciona independente se é RecyclerView ou não. Talvez esteja tendo outro problema. Se quiser criar outra pergunta não tem problema. Você que sabe.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/184083/problema-com-popupmenu-recycleradpter

Comment: Minha nova pergunta, Obrigado desde já :)