# Problema com PopupMenu Recycleradpter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Estou tendo problema com PopupMenu, quando clico no imageButtom falha e da o seguinte erro

> 02-14 15:27:26.531 11084-11092/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
>   02-14 15:27:38.842 11084-11084/com.robertoc.meublogclash E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.(MenuBuilder.java:223)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu.(PopupMenu.java:103)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu.(PopupMenu.java:78)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu.(PopupMenu.java:63)
>                                                                                     at com.robertoc.meublogclash.Comentarios$BloviewHolderr$1.onClick(Comentarios.java:190)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5217)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21349)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5585)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
>   02-14 15:27:39.073 11084-11084/com.robertoc.meublogclash E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: com.robertoc.meublogclash, PID: 11084
>                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.(MenuBuilder.java:223)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu.(PopupMenu.java:103)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu.(PopupMenu.java:78)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu.(PopupMenu.java:63)
>                                                                                  at com.robertoc.meublogclash.Comentarios$BloviewHolderr$1.onClick(Comentarios.java:190)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5217)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21349)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5585)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)

`@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();`

```
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Cont, BloviewHolderr> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Cont, BloviewHolderr>(

            Cont.class,
            R.layout.coment_row,
            BloviewHolderr.class,
            mQueryCurrentUser

    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(BloviewHolderr viewHolder, Cont model, int position) {
            final String user_key = getRef(position).getKey();
            //viewHolder.set_nome(model.getName());
            viewHolder.setComentario(model.getComentario());
            viewHolder.setUsername(model.getUsername());
            viewHolder.setFtperfil(getApplicationContext(), model.getFtperfil());

            viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent singleBlogIntent = new Intent (Comentarios.this, Perfil.class);
                    singleBlogIntent.putExtra("blog_id", user_key);
                    startActivity(singleBlogIntent);

                }
            });


        }

          }
    });
    mComentList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

}

public static class BloviewHolderr extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View mView;
    ImageButton mMenuPopup;
    Context mContext;
    public BloviewHolderr(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;
        mMenuPopup = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.menuComentario);

        mMenuPopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, mMenuPopup);//Linha do erro

                //Inflando o popup usando o arquivo xml
                popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_comentarioo, popup.getMenu());

                //Resgata o item clicado e mostra em um Toast
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                        return true;
                    }
                });
                popup.show();
            }
        });
    }
    public void setComentario (String comentario) {
        TextView post_coment = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.messageComent);
        post_coment.setText(comentario);
    }
    public void setUsername (String username){
        TextView post_nome = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.nameComent);
        post_nome.setText(username);


    }
```

O erro é na seguinte linha,
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, mMenuPopup);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro ocorre porque você não está instanciando o seu `mContext`. Você o declara mas ele continua nulo. Um exemplo de como está:

```
mContext = null; //como você não instanciou ele está nulo
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, mMenuPopup); // então dá erro aqui
```

Uma possível solução é você fazer com que o `mContext` recebe o contexto da *view*. Veja como deve ficar:

```
mContext = mView.getContext();
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, mMenuPopup);
```

Comment: Perfeito 100% funcional muito obrigado me ajudou bastante com as duas respostas

Comment: Olá Ack Lay , vim trabalhar com este código hoje e tenho um novo problema se puder me ajudar lá http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/186260/como-fa%c3%a7o-para-editar-uma-child-no-firebase/186265?noredirect=1#comment385243_186265

Comment: @WallaceRoberto não entendi. Qual seria o problema?